# How can I position two elements next to each other in the admin area?

Tags: theming

how can I position two elements next to each other in the admin area of Drupal 8.6.10?
I want to position the element **Channel Additional** next to the element "CHANNEL".
So that **Channel Additional** is next to **CHANNEL**.
How can I position this?
This positioning should only take place in the admin area.
[image]

Greetings

Comment: Other than using CSS?

Answer (score 0):

This could be placed inside a region to block. The admin ui has its own theme so any css changes should probably be in a sub theme to that.

In your theme you can define regions or blocks that can be styled or laid out with css. Drupal 8 is much more mobile friendly so you should probably consider how it should respond.

You can also define custom regions within your theme and place content accordingly if that is required.

Looking at your example it could be as simple as a couple of lines of css but as mentioned previously do consider how this will work on smaller viewports as well.